# Is it possible to displace my mesh based on the uv or normal orientation?

Tags: uv, geometry-nodes, displacement

I tried to use geo nodes to have better control about my scene performance later. But as you  can see the displacement is streched on one axis,  is it possible without stretching maybe with uv or  normal informations?
Thank for any idea you have.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Answer Pic]

This is how you displace a mesh based on its UVMap.
Bring in the UVMap via Named Attribute Node, plug it into a Vector Math Node set to Scale, the Scale value is for the mapping scale of the Texture. Plug into Vector of your Image Texture. Color Output into the Scale of another Scale Node, Normal into the Vector. A third Scale Node controls the Strength of the Displacement. Put that into the Offset, not the Position, of the Set Position Node.

If its based on a mesh primitive in Geometry Nodes, it has a UVMap Output you can use instead

If it is not UV unwrapped and you want to unwrap it procedurally, thats also possible but depending on the mesh it can be a bit tedious

Comment: @joachim Of course, will add a written description :)

Comment: I tried that out and it solved my problem very well. Thanks for that